# How to detect a known sound (short audio about 10sec) in a large audio file (5min)

Tags: java, audio-analysis

I am new working with audio file. Now I want to do the below task in Java. Is there any good tools or framework (like OpenCV for video and image) that can perform such task or not?

I have 5 audio files which each of them is about 10 sec long, and one larger audio file which is about 5 min. This large audio file is mixed from many other small audio files, in side maybe contained one or two ... of above 5 audio files.

Now I want to detect that which of above files are contained in this large audio file.

If you know please tell me how detect or done this stuff.

**Note:** I am using Java language.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I did not tried the coding, because I don't how to start. But I googled a lot and I found some result which says FFT, jAudio...etc can do, but when I download it there was good documentation or examples which shows how to use this. So now I want to someone tell me which frame good to use with examples, just like OpenCV which has good documentation and someone know how to use ...

Comment: Do you really have to stick to Java?If not, python have great Audio libraries.No need of preforming FFT manually.

Comment: I am not expert in Python, I am Java language, I think there maybe some library or wrapper for Java.

Answer (score 1):

[Musicg](https://code.google.com/p/musicg/) library may help and [this](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf) paper.